# Calculating mean or median in one function in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean

I have function that is supposed to compute, depending on user input, either the mean or median of a numpy.array. I have written it like this

```
 import numpy as np
 ...
 if input=='means':
      return np.mean(matrix, axis=1)
 if input=='median':
     return np.median(matrix, axis=1)
```

But this seems kinda cumbersome. I figured there might be a standard numpy function that takes the array as well as the operation as input. I'm thinking something similar to R's `tapply(X, Y, FUNCTION=Z)` where `Z` can be any kind of function. But I could not find anything in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.html) or on the Google...

- Is there something like this in Numpy?
- If there is no specific function, can someone think of a nice way of
  doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input string is `mean` instead of `means`, you could do:

```
return getattr(np, input)(matrix, axis=1)
```

Here the `getattr` call grabs the function you want from the numpy library. Then the second set of parentheses calls that function.

Comment: nice, I did not know about the `getattr`, thanks! Is there a reason why you changed axis from 1 to -1?

Comment: That was a typo. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need something specific to NumPy.

For example:

```
def myFunc(matrix, func, axis=1):
    return func(matrix)
```

Then, to use the function:

```
import numpy as np

#Create random matrix (10, 10)
mat = np.random.randint(100, size=(10, 10))
print myFunc(mat, np.mean)
```